# rds.logical_replication didn't change to 1 on aurora serverless AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I need to change the `rds.logical_replication` parameter to 1 in order to get `wal_level` to logical.

I already changed the `rds.logical_replication` [parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5cJJ.png), but when i run `SHOW rds.logical_replication` on my writer instance [still off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rttd0.png). Already tried applying the DB Cluster Parameter Group to the regional cluster and only to the writer instance.

I have [1 writer instance and 1 reader instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMXIP.png) but they are serverless.

Is the ploblem that Aurora is serverless?
How can i change the parameter correctly to see the changes in the writer instance?

---

I tried changing the `rds.logical_replication` to 1 in the `DB Cluster Parameter Group` and applied to the Regional Cluster.

I tried changing the `rds.logical_replication` to 1 in the `DB Cluster Parameter Group` and applied only to the writer instance.

I tried to make a Parameter Group with the need values, but  `rds.logical_replication` doesn't exist in the Parameter Group configuration.

Edit: I also rebooted the service.

I'm expecting to run `SHOW rds.logical_replication` and the variable is `ON`.

Comment: You cant change default parameter group, you should create new parameter group. 
Then update parameter and restart service.

Comment: I created my own parameter group.

Comment: Did you have a chance to fix it @Izaah ?

Answer (score 0):

Aurora PostgreSQL–based DB clusters running Aurora Serverless v1 have the following limitations:

> The logical replication feature available in Amazon RDS PostgreSQL and Aurora PostgreSQL isn't supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

> But for Aurora Serverless v2 is supported, please, be sure that
> Cluster Parameter Group is applied correctly and assign Cluster
> Parameter Group to Cluster level. Follow next procedure to enable
> rds.logical_replication. Stop and Start the Cluster to use new values.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.Configure

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-use-logical-replication/